# windows . how to automatic satrt apache2 in ubuntu windows

Tags: windows

I want to automatic start apache2 in ubuntu windows. So when startUp my laptop no longer running comment

```
service apache2 start
```

My OS is windows but i run apache in ubuntu windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make any program run at startup (even bash on windows) by going to **Run**, entering **shell:common startup** and adding a shortcut of the program in that folder.
Or simply place a shortcut of bash in the following location `C:\Users\<YOURUSERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

But you cannot startup apache2 as a service, only as daemons:

> Background tasks, daemons are now supported starting Insider build 17046. See the blog for more details. But, auto start of services is still not available.

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/511